# Insert nested records using rest class with existing ID of parent

Tags: apex

Hi I need to insert a `Subscription_Order__c` and `OrderProduct__c` record in Salesforce using Rest Api. `Subscription_Order__c` has a lookup to `Account` and `OrderProduct__c`has a master detail relationship to `Product__c` and a lookup to `Subscription_Order__c`.

I need to be the one who input the Id of Account to `Subscription_Order__c` and the Product__c id to `OrderProduct__c`

This is my sample code. I was able to do this with newly created Account but I need to use an id of an existing account.

I already tried this 
`global static string doPost(id AccountID){` 
and then 
`wso.subscriptionOrder.Account__c = AccountId ;`
But it's throwing an `Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization` error.

Your help is much appreaciated

```
@restResource(urlMapping='/buyproduct/*')
global with sharing class buyProduct{

    private class OrderWrapper{
        Account account;
        List<subscriptionOrderWrapper> so;
    }
    private class subscriptionOrderWrapper{
        Subscription_Order__c subscriptionOrder;
        List<OrderProduct__c> orderProductList;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static string doPost(){
          OrderWrapper container = (OrderWrapper)System.JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
            OrderWrapper.class);
       System.debug('#####1' + container);

        Account acc = container.account;
        insert acc;
        System.debug('#####2' + acc);


        List<Subscription_Order__c> soInsert = new List<Subscription_Order__c>();
        for(subscriptionOrderWrapper wso : container.so){
            //wso.subscriptionOrder.Account__c = acc.id;
            //Account__c = Inputted id of existing account id request body
            soInsert.add(wso.subscriptionOrder);
        }
        insert soInsert;
        System.debug('#####3' + soInsert);

        list<OrderProduct__c> opInsert = new List<OrderProduct__c>();
        for(subscriptionOrderWrapper wso : container.so){
            for(OrderProduct__c orderProduct : wso.orderProductList){
                orderProduct.Subscription_Order__c = wso.subscriptionOrder.Id;
                //subcription_Product__c = Inputted id of an existing product__c in request Body
                opInsert.add(orderProduct);
            }
        }
        insert opInsert;
        system.debug('#####4' + opInsert);
        return acc.Id;
    }
}
```

This is my request body when I am having the `Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization` error

```
    {

"so": [{
"subscriptionOrder":{
"Account" : 0016F00001sZtG0QAK
}

}]



}
```

Comment: Look into upsett

Comment: Can you post http request used when you got error.

Comment: Your wrapper class having variable `account` and in request its different 'Account__c'

Comment: `RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring()`this as to look like this: `{ account: {}, so: [] }` (stringified ofc)

Comment: @Reshma Hi it's only a type error. I'm using "Account" : "//ID of existing account"